# The following packages have unmet dependencies: linux-modules-5.15.0-50-generic

Tags: upgrade, dpkg, dependencies

I have updated my Ubuntu 22.04 LTS and I am getting some errors while updating and also coudn't able to install some softwares.

```
akhil@KHUSHI:~/.config$ sudo apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Update:

```
akhil@KHUSHI:~/.config$ sudo apt-get update
Hit:1 https://deb.nodesource.com/node_16.x jammy InRelease
Hit:2 http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/code stable InRelease                
Hit:3 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease               
Hit:4 https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/edge stable InRelease               
Hit:5 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu jammy InRelease                 
Hit:6 https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                  
Hit:7 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease     
Hit:8 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease
Hit:9 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
W: https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/dists/jammy/InRelease: Key is stored in legacy trusted.gpg keyring (/etc/apt/trusted.gpg), see the DEPRECATION section in apt-key(8) for details.
```

My kernal:

```
akhil@KHUSHI:~$ uname -r
5.15.0-52-generic
```

Full-Upgrade:

```
akhil@KHUSHI:~/.config$ sudo apt full-upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Fix Broken Packages:

```
akhil@KHUSHI:~/.config$ sudo apt -f install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  linux-image-unsigned-5.15.0-50-generic
Suggested packages:
  fdutils linux-doc | linux-source-5.15.0 linux-tools
  linux-headers-5.15.0-50-generic linux-modules-extra-5.15.0-50-generic
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  linux-image-5.15.0-50-generic
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  linux-image-unsigned-5.15.0-50-generic
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 1 to remove and 8 not upgraded.
6 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/11.6 MB of archives.
After this operation, 379 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
dpkg: linux-image-5.15.0-50-generic: dependency problems, but removing anyway as
 you requested:
 linux-modules-5.15.0-50-generic depends on linux-image-5.15.0-50-generic | linu
x-image-unsigned-5.15.0-50-generic; however:
  Package linux-image-5.15.0-50-generic is to be removed.
  Package linux-image-unsigned-5.15.0-50-generic is not installed.

(Reading database ... 331119 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing linux-image-5.15.0-50-generic (5.15.0-50.56) ...
/etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools:
update-initramfs: Deleting /boot/initrd.img-5.15.0-50-generic
/etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub:
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: error: failed to get canonical path of `rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_
zs8jjk'.
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub exited with return code 1
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-5.15.0-50-generic (--remove):
 installed linux-image-5.15.0-50-generic package post-removal script subprocess 
returned error exit status 1
dpkg: too many errors, stopping
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-5.15.0-50-generic
Processing was halted because there were too many errors.
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Update GRUB:

```
akhil@KHUSHI:~$ sudo update-grub
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: error: failed to get canonical path of `rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_zs8jjk'.
```

```
akhil@KHUSHI:~$ sudo apt-get install --reinstall grub-efi-amd64
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 linux-modules-5.15.0-50-generic : Depends: linux-image-5.15.0-50-generic but it is not going to be installed or
                                            linux-image-unsigned-5.15.0-50-generic but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Dependencies:

```
akhil@KHUSHI:~$ dpkg -L linux-image-5.15.0-50-generic
Package 'linux-image-5.15.0-50-generic' does not contain any files (!)
akhil@KHUSHI:~$ dpkg -l linux-image-5.15.0-50-generic
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name                          Version      Architecture Description
+++-=============================-============-============-===================>
pH  linux-image-5.15.0-50-generic 5.15.0-50.56 amd64        Signed kernel image>

[1]+  Stopped                 dpkg -l linux-image-5.15.0-50-generic
```

Force remove linux-modules-5.15.0-50-generic:

```
akhil@KHUSHI:~$ sudo dpkg --purge --force-remove-reinstreq linux-image-5.15.0-50-generic
(Reading database ... 329778 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing linux-image-5.15.0-50-generic (5.15.0-50.56) ...
/etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools:
update-initramfs: Deleting /boot/initrd.img-5.15.0-50-generic
/etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub:
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: error: failed to get canonical path of `rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_zs8jjk'.
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub exited with return code 1
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-5.15.0-50-generic (--purge):
 installed linux-image-5.15.0-50-generic package post-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-5.15.0-50-generic
```

```
akhil@KHUSHI:~$ sudo apt-get remove --purge linux-image-5.15.0-50-generic
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  linux-image-5.15.0-50-generic
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 22 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 11.6 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 329778 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing linux-image-5.15.0-50-generic (5.15.0-50.56) ...
/etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools:
update-initramfs: Deleting /boot/initrd.img-5.15.0-50-generic
/etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub:
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: error: failed to get canonical path of `rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_zs8jjk'.
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub exited with return code 1
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-5.15.0-50-generic (--remove):
 installed linux-image-5.15.0-50-generic package post-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 1
dpkg: too many errors, stopping
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-5.15.0-50-generic
Processing was halted because there were too many errors.
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

ZFS List:

```
akhil@KHUSHI:~$ zfs list
NAME                                               USED  AVAIL     REFER  MOUNTPOINT
bpool                                              291M  1.47G       96K  /boot
bpool/BOOT                                         290M  1.47G       96K  none
bpool/BOOT/ubuntu_zs8jjk                           290M  1.47G      290M  /boot
rpool                                              120G   326G      192K  /
rpool/ROOT                                        25.0G   326G      192K  none
rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_zs8jjk                          25.0G   326G     15.2G  /
rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_zs8jjk/srv                       216K   326G      216K  /srv
rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_zs8jjk/usr                       261M   326G      192K  /usr
rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_zs8jjk/usr/local                 260M   326G      260M  /usr/local
rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_zs8jjk/var                      9.53G   326G      192K  /var
rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_zs8jjk/var/games                 216K   326G      216K  /var/games
rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_zs8jjk/var/lib                  9.42G   326G     9.20G  /var/lib
rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_zs8jjk/var/lib/AccountsService   260K   326G      260K  /var/lib/AccountsService
rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_zs8jjk/var/lib/NetworkManager    728K   326G      728K  /var/lib/NetworkManager
rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_zs8jjk/var/lib/apt               107M   326G      107M  /var/lib/apt
rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_zs8jjk/var/lib/dpkg              124M   326G      124M  /var/lib/dpkg
rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_zs8jjk/var/log                  96.1M   326G     96.1M  /var/log
rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_zs8jjk/var/mail                  216K   326G      216K  /var/mail
rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_zs8jjk/var/snap                 8.00M   326G     8.00M  /var/snap
rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_zs8jjk/var/spool                 324K   326G      324K  /var/spool
rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_zs8jjk/var/www                   216K   326G      216K  /var/www
rpool/USERDATA                                    93.9G   326G      192K  /
rpool/USERDATA/akhil_pltcof                       80.9G   326G     80.9G  /home/akhil
rpool/USERDATA/root_pltcof                        13.0G   326G     13.0G  /root
rpool/keystore                                     518M   327G     63.5M  -
```

I couldn't able to install new applications or run some of the existing apps or get software updates because of this issue.

Comment: Are you using ZFS? [ZFS Grub probe error failed to get canonical path of dev disk name](https://askubuntu.com/questions/827126/zfs-grub-probe-error-failed-to-get-canonical-path-of-dev-disk-name)

Comment: I have shown the output of "zfs list" command @mchid

Answer (score 4):

##### Problems:

First of all, you have some Ubuntu Impish repositories that I assume were manually added. Ubuntu Impish (21.10) is now EOL so it's no longer supported and the repositories have since been disabled.

Next, the [AMCG ppa was last available for Ubuntu Xenial](https://launchpad.net/%7Eamcg/+archive/ubuntu/ppa#yui_3_10_3_1_1680481045270_74).

Under **"Overview of published packages"**, click on the dropdown menu for "**Published in: Any series**" filter and you will see this PPA was only available for Xenial and Trusty.

[image: screenshot of the launchpad page for the amcg ppa showing only packages for Xenial and Trusty were published]

Additionally, [Anbox support ppa is no longer necessary on kernels newer than version 5.0](https://github.com/anbox/anbox/issues/1289#issuecomment-970290567). Any Ubuntu version newer than 19.04 does not need the extra kernel modules provided by the anbox-support PPA.

[image: Starting with Ubuntu 19.04 binder and ashmem are now build with the standard Ubuntu kernel (>= 5.0) and you don't have to install the modules from the PPA anymore.]

##### Solution:

The easiest solution would be to delete or comment out the lines for Ubuntu Impish in your sources list file.

Then, delete the unneeded PPA repositories by using the `add-apt-repository -r` command:

```
sudo add-apt-repository -r ppa:amcg/ppa
sudo add-apt-repository -r ppa:morphis/anbox-support
```

Also, it looks like you may need to reinstall the Brave browser because it's throwing a signature error. **Be sure to backup your current Brave Browser in case you lose your bookmarks and settings.** Although this is probably outside of the scope for this question, you can ask the community and open a new question if you need help with this.

And then run:

```
sudo apt update
```

and if you get no errors:

```
sudo apt full-upgrade
```

and if you have problems you may need to run:

```
sudo apt -f install
```

with no packages mentioned — just run the last command as is and it will try to fix any problems with broken packages. **Always be sure to pay attention to the output and only select Y if you are sure you want to proceed as this may delete or uninstall packages.**

When you no longer have any errors, verify everything is updated/upgraded:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt full-upgrade
```

Comment: Please post any errors. It looks like you had 2 PPAs for anbox-support so if the `add-apt-repository -r` command doesn't delete both of them, either run the `sudo add-apt-repository -r ppa:morphis/anbox-support` command again to delete the second one OR as a last resort, simply locate the file in your `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` directory that corresponds to the morphis/anbox-support PPA and manually delete the file.

Comment: I am facing similar problem while trying to install or upgrade with linux-image-5.15.0-50 generic I followed above solution still the same. Please advise.

Comment: @AndyM ask a new question, don't post it as an answer or comment